# calling help(MyClass) also shows base class attributes: how to avoid that?

Tags: python-3.x, documentation, metaclass, derived

MyClass  is derived from "list": MyClass(list)
I would like to document MyClass nicely.
Unfortunately, when trying  help(MyClass), 
I get my own documentation, but I also get a lot of stuff about "list".

Would there be a simple way to control that?
I read something about metaclasses, but I was unable to do something.

Thanks for your suggestions,

Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is what `help` does. It introspects into your class and show the name and the associated `__doc__` for each callable attribute in the class, and that is not customizable.

Attributes of the superclass are considered attributes of the class, and are reached in the introspection Python's help do.

Metaclasses could even  be used to customize the output one gets when he does "dir" on your class - but they do not change the output of the help text. To change "dir" output, create a metaclass implementing a `__dir__` method, and return a list of what you want visible as dir's output.

```
class M(type):
   def __dir__(self):
       return []  # blank dir contents

class MyList(list, metaclass=M):
   ...
```

On the other hand, the help contents displayed for `list` attributes are not that verbose, and can actually be helpful - if you override any methods to do something different than described, the incorrect text won't show anyway. So you might just live with it.

Another tip is that instead of subclassing `list` you might prefer to subclass `collections.abc.MutableSequence` instead, and use an inner agregated (normal) list to keep your data: that will require you to implement a lot less methods to have your class working properly as a sequence and is preferable in most cases to subclass list. That won't change `help`'s verbosity though.

Comment: Thanks a lot jsbueno !
I was missing the  "metaclass=M"  thing.
I naïvely had imagined the link was established in the __init__() .
There still remains a  "Method resolution order: ..." in the help, but that's not a big issue.

Comment: It "can"... but I'd say it is not the right thing to do. You can technically replace a module by a custom class, eeplacing the entry in the `sys.modules` dict after it is loaded or by customizing the "import" pipeline. 
Although maybe what you need is a framework to compile proper dcumentation from docstrings, like sphynx.