# __dir__() in class and in metaclass

Tags: python, metaclass

I just used a metaclass for the first time.
The purpose was to get control of the help() output for a class or instance.
Specifying attributes in the __dir__() function of the metaclass allowed me to control the help content.
However, I observed that for intellisense/code_completion, within Jupyter, it was the __dir__() function of the class itself that matters.

It's enough for me to understand the fact.
However, I would like to know the reason for that.

Thanks for a clarification.

Comment: help content? __dir__ is the implementation of `dir()` and should print attributes dict of the object

Comment: Yes, but help() from Jupyter seems to use \__dir__() to decide about the help content. I don't know if this is specific to Jupyter or if there is a more general reason for this behaviour. Nevertheless, why and when would the \__dir__() from the class or the metaclass be used?

Answer (score 0):

As I had stated in the [other answer about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46822320/108205), Python does not define how the contents of `help` are picked. And using the `metaclass` `__dir__` is something that will work due to the nature of the language, but third party modules certainly won't expect it to return custom results, different from the class's dir, as it is not a common thing.

So, what gives is that you are trying to customize features that are not customizable - you will either have to create a new class that proxies to all uneeded user methods, and therefore can hide from help and dir what you don't want to show, or create an entire aplication that just does what you need instead of relying on Jupiter notebooks to show your specific instructions and only those instructions.

Overall, if you are using a metaclass for other motives, ok, but if you are making use of a metaclass just to try to override `help` output, I'd say that is an incorrect use already.

Another option is to stick a manually callable "help2" method in your class, that prints only your desired output. Then you document on the main class docstring "please, use `classname.help2()` to learn the usage.", and otherwise leave `__dir__`  alone.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. It's the first time I want to document my code! I like the idea of docstring's but I am a bit disappointed when using them. My aim was to avoid mixing my stuff with a lot of useless extras.

Comment: I think I also mentioned that you should take a look at sphinx, and how it can take advantage of properly formatted docstrings to generate firstclass offline (that is, "not help") documentation for all your project. You really should go there. https://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/docstring_python.html